# Looking for software allowing for Arduino-based project "mocking" / "wireframing"

Tags: electronics

I'd like to be able to import a number of components (e.g Arduinos, MPU6050s, displays, motor drivers, LEDs, etc) into an app of some sort then be able to wire those components to each other for the purpose of being able to refer to this crude schematic at a later point or to share it with others. I tried importing things into Eagle, but that seemed like an absolute overkill (if Eagle can be used for something like this, what would the best approach be?). Does software that solves that particular issue exist? Think of it like wireframing for hobby electronics projects...

Please forgive the absolute layman explanation.

Comment: Fritzing is the normal Arduino user's schematic tool.

Comment: or https://www.tinkercad.com

Comment: @Majenko Absolutely what I was after! Thank you!

Comment: tinkercad is nice because it will actually run the sketch and simulate hardware like blinking LEDs.